# Conversion date in the format timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, timestamp

I have a date as a `timestamp` . I have to replace it every day on the date of beginning of `7:00:00 hours` a day from the date of timestamp for example . `11-07-2016 7:00:00`

For example, I have a date after changing `837072216 837241200` it will need a scalar function .

Comment: good luck with that, let us know how you get on

Answer (score 6):

Your question is very unclear. In fact, there is no actual question...

Never-the-less, you appear to be asking about a conversion from `timestamp` to a `date` or `time`. This is not possible; despite its name, `timestamp` does not represent a date(time). It is used for versioning of rows, and it's deprecated and replaced by `rowversion`. [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx).